# AngularJS combining two arrays with modifying

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have following two array objects

```
27A: {id: 228, swift_code: "27", field_description: "Sequence of Total", 
line_description: "1/1 (Number)(Total)", commercial: false}

31B: {id: 230, swift_code: "31C", field_description: "Date of Issue", 
line_description: "dd/mm/yyyy", commercial: false}

31C: {id: 242, swift_code: "31D", field_description: "Expiry Date/Place 
(dd/mm/yyyy)", line_description: "IN SINGAPORE", commercial: true}
```

my second array

```
67: {id: 228, swift_code: "27", field_description: "Sequence of Total", 
line_description: "1/1 (Number)(Total)", commercial: false}

44: {id: 230, swift_code: "31C", field_description: "Date of Issue", 
line_description: "dd/mm/yyyy", commercial: false}

12: {id: 242, swift_code: "31D", field_description: "Expiry Date/Place 
(dd/mm/yyyy)", line_description: "IN SINGAPORE", commercial: true}
```

i want to combined these two array together like bellow without modifying the order which means first array come first second array second

like bellow

```
27A: {id: 228, swift_code: "27", field_description: "Sequence of Total", 
line_description: "1/1 (Number)(Total)", commercial: false}

31B: {id: 230, swift_code: "31C", field_description: "Date of Issue", 
line_description: "dd/mm/yyyy", commercial: false}

31C: {id: 242, swift_code: "31D", field_description: "Expiry Date/Place 
(dd/mm/yyyy)", line_description: "IN SINGAPORE", commercial: true}

67: {id: 228, swift_code: "27", field_description: "Sequence of Total", 
line_description: "1/1 (Number)(Total)", commercial: false}

44: {id: 230, swift_code: "31C", field_description: "Date of Issue", 
line_description: "dd/mm/yyyy", commercial: false}

12: {id: 242, swift_code: "31D", field_description: "Expiry Date/Place 
(dd/mm/yyyy)", line_description: "IN SINGAPORE", commercial: true}
```

i have used merge and array copy but its modifying the order

```
angular.merge(arraiobj1, arraiobj2);
```

Comment: Can u try push?

Comment: it is also not working

Comment: const mergedArr = [...firstArr, ...secArr]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're talking about objects, not arrays. Arrays have only numeric indexes.

But JSON doesn't keep order, contrary to `PHP` and the like.

[Javascript - maintain key order when going from object -> array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31409156/5535245)

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31409887/781153 for instance.

> If you intended for this to describe an ordered set, you're not following the rules of JSON. The data happens to be ordered (because that's how character sequences work), but JSON semantics freely allow an implementation to disregard the order of name/value pairs completely when considering the data present in the input string.
>
> As a practical matter, most JavaScript engines will usually choose to report key names in the order their properties were created. However, this behavior is not required by any specification (and is sometimes inconsistent in edge cases), and so could legally differ between engines and versions.

The best way to handle your order, is to use numeric array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [angular.extend()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend), it will append your first object into second.

```
angular.extend(arraiobj1, arraiobj2);
```

Comment: nope it is still modifying the order of the array

Comment: Is it an array or object? because, in the object, the order won't matter.