# Why HttpClient Angular order json field

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I just discovered a small problem coming from HttpClient, when I try to fetch data from my api:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/api/test/test?status=None").subscribe((data)=>{
    console.log(data);
})}
```

It seems to order the json field in alphabetic order. Here is the result from Postman:

```
"total": {
    "error": 321,
    "run": 338,
    "desc": 1000
}
```

And here is from Angular HttpClient:

```
total: {
    desc: 321,
    error: 1000,
    run: 338
}
```

Did someone have the same issue or just a tip to force HttpClient to not alphabetically order the field?

Comment: In your example the response is ordered in Postman but NOT ordered in HttpClient. Did I miss something?

Comment: Yeah sorry, it just fake the field. I correct it to match it to my question

Comment: Neither result is in order. Also the result from Angular in your question is not in JSON format. Please proofread before posting

Comment: this is how browser represents objects passed from json. you should not rely on the order of properties in javacsript objects. ordered collections are for example arrays. on other js engines order of props can theoretically be different, but afaik all popular browsers would make properties go in order

Comment: Do NOT rely on the order of an object. Use arrays/iterables instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - maintain key order when going from object -> array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31409156/javascript-maintain-key-order-when-going-from-object-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of a JSON object is insignificant.

According to [json.org](https://www.json.org/json-en.html):

> "An object is an **unordered** set of name/value pairs"

If you have to depend on the order of an object, then you might want to use an iterable data type like array that can be used in JSON.